# QTreeWidgetItem is Copyable not Ediable

Tags: qt

It's possible to make users to be able to copy the DisplayRole value of QTreeWidgetItem, without enabling them to edit it (by setting `Qt::ItemIsEditable`).

Thanks

Comment: Select an item + Ctrl-C?

Comment: I also set the item is not selectable

Comment: I've disabled all interaction with widget items and still want to be able to copy item text? That sounds really weird.

Comment: The problem is I only want one col to be selectable, If I set `Qt::ItemIsSelectable`, all the cols become selectable, that's not what I want